# Particles connected by a rod - impact of the rod not being light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

> I have two particles $P$ and $Q$ connected by a rod, with $P$ vertically above $Q$. The rod accelerates upwards by some vertical force $F$ acting at $P$. Each particle $P$ and $Q$ experience some constant, fixed resistive force.

In model 1, the rod is considered light.

In model 2, the rod is not considered light.

I am interested in the impact of the rod not being light on the tension in the rod.

My logic is that it will have no impact because if I consider the forces acting at $P$, I can form the equation:   $$F - m_pg - R_p - T= m_p a$$where $R_p$ is the resistive force at $P$. Thus I conclude the tension is independent of the mass of the rod since it does not appear in this resolution.

Is this correct? [image]

Comment: By light and not light do you mean massless and with mass? Is the rod subject to the same resistive force?

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes light is being taken to mean massless in my course. The resistive force is the force acting against the motion (so acting vertically downwards). There is a resistive force acting downwards at $P$ and one acting down at $Q$.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you drew a diagram of the components of this assembly showing all the forces acting on it and where they act.  For example, I'm not sure what you mean by "each particle P and Q experience some constant fixed resistive force". Can I assume this is some external downward force? Is it applied to each particle individually or in combination? In your equation, where is the downward force due to the mass of Q?

Comment: @BobD I’ve now added a diagram.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove So this appears to be your free body diagram (FBD) on the assembly . It looks like Rp and Rq are separate external forces individually applied to P and Q. Is that correct? If it is, why is Rp in your equation but not Rq. Also, why is the downward force of gravity on Rp in your equation but not Rq. Also the free body diagram should show all the EXTERNAL forces on the assembly. The tension in the rod is an INTERNAL force. It should not be in the FBD, nor should T be in your equation. T is in a diagram and in an equation if you did a FBD with the rod cut.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove And lastly it seems to me the weight of the rod would certainly affect the upward acceleration of the assembly.

Comment: This is because I have considered $P$ and $Q$ separately for the resolution. I have no considered the system and I think I am allowed to do this since the system moves in the same, single line. When I consider $P$, the only forces acting on it directly are $F$, $R_p$, $T$ and $m_p$, hence giving $F - R_p - T - m_p = m_p a$

Comment: @BobD The supplied diagram is obviously not a free body diagram, since it is not including "free bodies". However, I think the diagram is still useful in showing what forces the OP wants to have present in the system. The OP is also right in the posted equation if you are performing Newton's second law on just point $P$. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @AaronStevens I see now that he says the equation is for all the forces on P (I thought it should have been for the entire assembly since it acts as one rigid body). In any event, I agree with your answer since covers all the external forces acting on the assembly as I had suggested and shows that the tension force is irrelevant in determining the acceleration of the assembly. Finally, whether or not the rod has mass certainly effects the acceleration of the assembly.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Does my answer supply what you are looking for?

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, sorry forgot to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can essentially model this system as three objects stuck together. Let us first consider the massless rod case:

If we treat the system as a whole and apply Newton's laws, we get
$$\sum_i F_i=(m_p+m_q)a=F-(m_p+m_q)g-R_p-R_q$$

Since we will assume the system is rigid, everything moves with the same acceleration. Therefore, this gives us the acceleration of just point $P$ as well:
$$a_p=\frac{F-(m_p+m_q)g-R_p-R_q}{m_p+m_q}$$

But applying Newton's second law on just particle $P$ we get:
$$\sum F_{p,i}=m_pa_p=F-m_pg-R_p-T$$

Equating the two accelerations (since they are the same) we get:
$$\frac{F-(m_p+m_q)g-R_p-R_q}{m_p+m_q}=\frac{F-m_pg-R_p-T}{m_p}$$

Solving this expression for $T$ gives us
$$T=\frac{Fm_q+m_pR_q-m_qR_p}{m_p}$$

This gives us the tension in the rod for the massless rod case. A similar method can be used to analyze what happens when the rod has mass, which I will leave for you to do.

I will say one thing though. For the rod with mass, there is no longer a single tension in the rod. In order for the rod with mass to accelerate upwards, there must be a different force magnitude acting on each end of the rod, and the magnitude of the tension in the rod will varying linearly along the rod between these two values (assuming a uniform mass density in the rod). So you might need to reformulate your question for this case.